# message wait on a AS/400 V7R2 power 8 box " java program completed with exit code 1"

Tags: java, ibm-midrange

```
 File QPRINT created in library QTEMP.                                    
 Member QPRINT added to file QPRINT in QTEMP.                             
 Operation for program device or member QPRINT, file QPRINT in library    
   QTEMP is  not valid.                                                   
 Java program completed with exit code 1                                  
 Function check. JVA0122 unmonitored by STRCMSSVR at statement *N,        
   instruction X'00A8'.                                                   
 JVA0122 received by STRCMSSVR at *N. (C D I R)
```

I am getting the above logs when looking in to MSGW for a job in AS/400 V7R1 Power 8 box. Can anybody here help me on how to trouble shoot and come out of MSGW ?

Comment: Could you post the code that generates this error?

Comment: STRCMSSVR  isn't a OS command, if it's code you wrote, post the code.  Otherwise contact the vendor of the product you're trying to use.

Comment: You get out of MSGW by answering the message with a `C`